# about update data in Android Studio and SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 questions want to ask about android studio and sqlite.

1) I am trying to run my project in emulator or phone. When I want to return to previous activity by pressing the return button(return function for phone) but it close all my project.But I saw my friend's can return to previous activity by pressing the return button.May I know how and why??

2) I had done update function for my project.The situation is when userA go to "view profile" activity and click edit info, another activity that call "updateinfo" will come out.Then after userA update his information by clicking update button.It's successful update and go back to "view profile" activity to see his updated profile.

But the problem I faced is it does not show out the updated information.It just show a blank "view profile" activity without any information that updated or haven updated.

What should I do?

here my database update function

```
     public boolean updateProfile(String username, String password, String email, String phone)
   {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       values.put (COL_2,username);
       values.put(COL_3,password);
       values.put(COL_4,email);
       values.put(COL_5,phone);

      db.update(Table_NAME,values,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{username});
       db.close();
       return true;
   }
```

here is my updateinfo activity function

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etEmail,etPhone,etPassword,etConPassword,etUsername;
String password,conpassword,Email,Phone;
Button bUpdate;
DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etConPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConPassword);
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    bUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
    etEmail.setText(email);
    String phone = i.getStringExtra("phone");
    etPhone.setText(phone);
    String username = i.getStringExtra("username");
    etUsername.setText(username);

    bUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            conpassword = etConPassword.getText().toString();
            Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            Phone = etPhone.getText().toString();

            if (!(password.equals(conpassword))) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Passwords are not matching", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etPassword.setText("");
                etConPassword.setText("");
                etEmail.setText("");
                etPhone.setText("");
            } else if (etPassword.length() == 0 || etConPassword.length() == 0 || etEmail.length() == 0 || etPhone.length() == 0) {
                etPassword.setError("Please complete all information");
                etConPassword.setError("Please complete all information");
                etEmail.setError("Please complete all information");
                etPhone.setError("Please complete all information");
            } else if (etPassword.length() < 6) {
                etPassword.requestFocus();
                etPassword.setError("Password at least 6 characters");
                etPassword.setText("");
                etConPassword.setText("");
                etEmail.setText("");
                etPhone.setText("");
            } else {
                boolean isUpdate = DB.updateProfile(etUsername.getText().toString(),etPassword.getText().toString(),etEmail.getText().toString(),etPhone.getText().toString());
                if(isUpdate == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(EditProfile.this, MyProfile.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my viewprofile activity function

```
public class MyProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText etName,etEmail,etPhone,etShow;
Button bEdit;
String fullname,email,phone;
DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations(this);
PersonalData profileInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);



    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    bEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
    etShow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etShow);


    fullname = etName.getText().toString();
    email = etEmail.getText().toString();
    phone = etPhone.getText().toString();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String username = i.getStringExtra("username");
    etShow.setText(username);
    profileInfo = db.getAllinfo(username);
    etName.setText(profileInfo.get_name());
    etEmail.setText(profileInfo.get_email());
    etPhone.setText(profileInfo.get_phone());


    bEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyProfile.this,EditProfile.class);
            i.putExtra("email", etEmail.getText().toString());;
            i.putExtra("phone", etPhone.getText().toString());;
            i.putExtra("username", etShow.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you always start new activity and finish the last activity

`startActivity(i);
 finish();`

**dont finish it if you want to go back later**, you can go back to last activity with finish(); or pressing back in phone

2. you just need to call finish() when update success (you need to implement answer number 1 first)

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

<s>Intent i = new Intent(EditProfile.this, MyProfile.class);</s>

startActivity(i);

finish();

in MyProfile make the username variable **global**

```
String username;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    username = i.getStringExtra("username");
....
}
```

last,this code need to be inside **onResume()**

```
etShow.setText(username);
profileInfo = db.getAllinfo(username);
etName.setText(profileInfo.get_name());
etEmail.setText(profileInfo.get_email());
etPhone.setText(profileInfo.get_phone());
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean update(editProfile.EUsers eusers){

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();

    String username = eusers.getUsername();
    String password = eusers.getPassword();
    int id = eusers.getId();
    contentvalues.put(editProfile.EUsers.COL3_PASSWORD,password);
    contentvalues.put(editProfile.EUsers.COL2_USERNAME,username);

    int res =db.update(editProfile.EUsers.TABLE_NAME,values,editProfile.EUsers.COL1_ID+" = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    if(res >0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution to include an explanation of how you code solves the OP's problem :)